# Refering with type and not only number

Tags: latex

when I want to refer to for example an equation, I do the following:

```
\begin{align}
    R= \frac{c * \Delta T}{2}
    \label{eqn:Range}
\end{align}

Now I want to refer to \ref{eqn:Range}.
```

Then the output is the following:

*Now I want to refer to 3.4.*

I would like that the output is already:

*Now I want to refer to **equation** 3.4.*

Without me having to write equation manually.

The same goes also for tables and figures.
Especially for figures, I would like to know if there are more possibilities to display the reference.
For example with the following:

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{Example} 
    \caption{Example caption}
    \label{fig:ExampleRef}
\end{figure}{}
```

I would like to be able to get also the caption displayed: *Figure 1.1: Example caption*.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have a look at the cleveref package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a job for the `cleveref` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    R= \frac{c * \Delta T}{2}
    \label{eqn:Range}
\end{align}

Now I want to refer to \cref{eqn:Range}.


\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{example-image-duck} 
    \caption{Example caption}
    \label{fig:ExampleRef}
\end{figure}

\cref{fig:ExampleRef}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I could see in the documentation of cleveref anything to also include the caption. Did I oversee it or do I need another package for that?

Comment: @Metz To repeat the caption have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/301076 (but please consider carefully if this is really a good idea, repeating so much information will drastically decrease the information-to-noise level of your document)